Stuck on boot loop when Arducam is attached
Ive been working with two cameras recently. The first one is a 64 megapixel hawkeye and the second one is a imx477. Both were working fine recently untill I took the lens off the 64 megapixel camera in hopes of attatching a different lens to it. When I tried attatching the camera with it attatched to the pi (4) it got stuck in a boot loop. it boots fine with the imx477 or without any camera attatched. I tried putting the lens back on and booting that way but still problem. Any ideas? thank you.

I think Arducam are the best people to ask.  They are likely to have a better idea of what you broke.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
